# Moment.js time wrong when DST is on

Tags: momentjs

Don't understand why the examples on [moment-timezone page](https://momentjs.com/timezone/) give me different result than what they say they should.

Running these statements give me date with my current local time for each instance:

```
var jun = moment("2014-06-01T12:00:00Z");
var dec = moment("2014-12-01T12:00:00Z");

jun.tz('America/Los_Angeles').format('ha z');  // 5am PDT **I get 7am** 
dec.tz('America/Los_Angeles').format('ha z');  // 4am PST **I get 6am**
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

Found the issue was due to missing time zone data. After loading time zone data I get the expected results, below; how to load time zone data

[http://momentjs.com/timezone/docs/#/data-loading/][1]